# react-refresh: OriginalFactory is undefined | Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: webpack, react-refresh

While trying to use moduleFederationPlugin from webpack, we are getting below error:

` Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

originalFactory.call(this, moduleObject, moduleExports, webpackRequire);`

Its seems to be an issue with react-refresh plugin, the above line is breaking and originalFactory is undefined.

I wanted to create a Micro - FrontEnd architecture.

I was expecting the code to run without any issues.